# How to make a specific route return JSON response on Flutter web project

Tags: flutter, firebase

On a Flutter web project, I want to make a specific route behave like an endpoint returning JSON response, that should have all the processing capabilities to talk to Firebase etc but return the JSON, not the regular flutter loader HTML canvas.

https://example.com -> loads website
https://example.com/api/ -> return JSON, no UI, just JSON text with JSON headers

Anyone tried this, or any ideas how to solve this?

Case: I'm building this app which has integration of payments, and the payment processor is posting us back some http post calls to inform us about the orders, so we need a way to listen to those and process those information, and return them JSON response, not HTML, entire web site is hosted on Firebase hosting, uses firestorm as database.

Comment: Sounds like you want to support a vendor hook, but from a flutter app running in a browser.  That's not possible.  You'll need to have a service running somewhere that can serve as an intermediary.